# How to migrate the custom product attribute created in test environment to production?

Tags: magento2, data-migration

I have created many (more than 5) custom product attributes in a new attribute set in dev environment, do I have to create them manually ? or is there an easy way to migrate them to other environments like Test, Integration ,Performance and production environment?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use InstallData or UpgradeData script to add eav attribute programmatically sothat when `setup:upgrade` executes, attributes are added.

Follow:- https://devdocs.magento.com/videos/fundamentals/add-new-product-attribute/